# No network access through PPTP

Tags: vpn, pptp

I would like to be able to connect to the office network and access the internet through that network and the servers within the network. I use a server running Ubuntu Server (fully updated) behind a router which acts as PPTP server. It is set up like this:

#### Office

Router delivers IP's in the range of 192.168.1.1-253, the router has IP 192.168.1.254. The Ubuntu Server running PPTP server has IP 192.168.1.102 (static, delivered by the router).

#### Home

A network using the same range (192.168.1.1-255). I tried to connect through Ubuntu and MacOSX, both give the same result.

#### PPTP Settings

- `/etc/pptpd.conf`

  ```
  localip 192.168.1.102
  remoteip 192.168.1.110-200
  ```
- `/etc/sysctl.conf`

  ```
  net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```
- `/etc/rc.local`

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
  ```
- `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options`

  ```
  ms-dns 8.8.8.8
  ms-dns 8.8.4.4
  ```

  (not really necessary I guess, but just to be sure)

Of course, I forwarded port 1723 to 192.168.1.102 and opened the port on the Ubuntu server (`ufw allow pptp`)

#### Current situation

I could connect to the VPN and also access the internet. According to www.whatismyip.com I do have the office IP, so that part works. I am able to ping 192.168.1.102, but not any of the other addresses within the network. I just don't know what to do anymore. I have followed all steps in many tutorials, but that doesn't change anything. One suggestion I also tried:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o ppp+ -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

I don't know exactly what that does, but it didn't work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same address range for both networks is a great misconfiguration.

I suggest:

- Use 192.168.1.0/24 (that means 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.255) for your
  office.
- Use 192.168.2.0/24 (or any other private network, but not 192.168.1.0/24) at home.
- Check that the address range your PPTP-server manages (192.168.1.110-200) is NOT managed by the DHCP servers (if any) on your networks.